# '/bin/bash: Permission denied' when trying to ssh to CentOS 7 after remote GNOME desktop install

Tags: centos, ssh, gnome

As the title states, I cant ssh to a server anymore after remotely installing the GNOME desktop (`'yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"'`) on a Centos 7 machine.
SSH becomes this:

```
ssh root@ipaddress

Last login: Wed Dec  4 20:04:35 2019 from X.X.X.X
/bin/bash: Permission denied
Connection to ipaddress closed.'
```

Id be grateful for any insights into whats going on and how to fix it.

Comment: It seems like `SELinux` is the culprit here. You need to `touch /.autorelabel` and reboot your machine. But before doing that you somehow need to log in to the remote machine.

Comment: SELinux is set to Permissive, before I started setting up

Comment: Are you able to log in to the machine somehow and see what `ls -lZ /bin/bash` tells you? Is the `/root` directory there?  Have you set `PermitRootLogin yes` in the `sshd_config` file?  What does `ssh  -vvv root@ipaddress`  tell you?

Comment: I cant login currently but from my previous attempts, I did enable `PermitRootLogin`, I didnt check `-lZ` though.
I'll check in once Im done reinstalling

Comment: You were right, it was an SELinux thing, which was weird since it is set to permissive. Leaving /.autorelabel in fixed the issue.

Comment: Great and thanks for confirming it!